# Order By ABS with a sub-query in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, subquery

I am trying to execute the following query in Microsoft Access

```
SELECT Weights.Group, Abs(Wt-(Select avg(Wt) from Weights w2 where Weights.Group = w2.Group)) AS Rank
FROM Weights
WHERE (((Weights.[Selected])=1))
ORDER BY Abs(Wt-(Select avg(Wt) from Weights w2 where Weights.Group = w2.Group));
```

against the following table

```
ID  Wt  Selected    Group
1   911 1   1
2   912 1   1
3   913 0   1
4   914 1   1
5   880 1   2
6   890 1   2
7   885 1   2
8   886 1   2
```

When I execute the query I get an invalid syntax error.  If I try to just reference column 2 in the Order By Clause it appears as if it orders by the literal 2 rather than column 2.  Anyone have any experience with this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will have to wrap it:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
       Weights.Group, 
       Abs([Wt]-
         (Select avg(Wt) from Weights w2 where Weights.Group = w2.Group)) AS Rank
    FROM Weights
    WHERE Weights.Selected=1)
ORDER BY Rank
```