# MS Access SQL - Problem with subquery and function in ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, sql-order-by

The senario is that some people apply for some positions.
So there are `tApplicant`, `tPosition` and a join table `tPreferences` for a many-to-many relationship between them.

I need to build a SQL expression where these should happen:

1. get some fields from a join of `tApplicant` and `tPosition` into a new table.
2. create a new field called `AM` which should be either 1 or 0.
   1 = If `tApplicant.applicationID` is found in a third not relevant table called `tInfo`.
   0 = If `tApplicant.applicationID` is not found there.
3. `ORDER BY AM`.

It is executed in VBA. This is what I 've got so far:

```
sSQL = "SELECT tApplicant.applicationID, tApplicant.name, tApplicant.ID, tPreferences.fld3, " & _
       "NZ((SELECT 1 FROM tInfo WHERE tInfo.applicationID = tApplicant.applicationID), 0) AS AM " _
       "INTO " & sTable & " FROM tPreferences INNER JOIN tApplicant " & _
       "ON tPreferences.IDapplic = tApplicant.applicationID " & _
       "WHERE tPreferences.IDposit = " & rsRos!ID & ";"
CurrentDB.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
```

It seems like step 3 cannot be done.
Adding `ORDER BY AM`, throws `Run-time error '3061'. Too few parameters. Expected 1.`.
While adding `ORDER BY NZ((SELECT 1 FROM tInfo WHERE tInfo.applicationID = tApplicant.applicationID), 0)`, throws `Run-Time Error 3075: Syntax Error in Query Expression 'NZ((SELECT 1 FROM tAMEA WHERE tAMEA.aitisiID = tAiton.aitisiID), 0'.`.
If omitted, everything works fine but there's no ORDER BY.
How can I achieve this?
PS: If values 1 and 0 for AM make things complicated, and some other values instead could be easier to get with the query, it will be OK, I will deal with this in the rest of the code.

Comment: What's the error, and how are you executing it? `Nz` is an application-level function and is unavailable in most contexts

Comment: @ErikA I 've updated the question based on your comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ErikA and @Gustav 's answers pointed me to the right direction.  Thank you both for your time.

The problem in this case was that I tried to use a subquery in the ORDER BY clause. Which I found out now that is not allowed. [eg. see here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-subquery/)
More over, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530535/order-by-abs-with-a-sub-query-in-microsoft-access), which makes mine a possible duplicate. Here it is suggested to wrap the query.
So I firstly `SELECT` the data in no order with the subquery ***and then***, `INSERT INTO` the new table using `ORDER BY` with the new column of the subquery.

So I'm posting what finally worked for me.

```
sSQL = "SELECT * INTO " & sTable & " FROM (" & _
       "SELECT tApplicant.applicationID, tApplicant.name, tApplicant.ID, tProtimisi.fld3, " & _
       "NZ((SELECT 1 FROM tInfo WHERE tInfo.applicationID = tApplicant.applicationID), 0) AS AM " & _
       "FROM tPreferences INNER JOIN tApplicant " & _
       "ON tPreferences.IDapplic = tApplicant.applicationID " & _
       "WHERE tPreferences.IDposit = " & rsRos!ID & ") " & _
       "ORDER BY AM DESC;"
CurrentDb.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
```

Answer (score 2):

`Nz` is an application-level function (technically, a method of the `Access.Application` object exposed as a function. It is unavailable for use in DAO.

`CurrentDb.Execute` is using DAO.

There are two rewrite possibilities:

1. Rewrite to avoid `Nz`:

   ```
   IIF((SELECT 1 FROM tInfo WHERE tInfo.applicationID = tApplicant.applicationID) IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)
   ```

   Or my preferred rewrite:

   ```
   ORDER BY EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tInfo WHERE tInfo.applicationID = tApplicant.applicationID) DESC
   ```
2. Rewrite to `DoCmd.RunSQL` which does allow these functions (and suppress warnings as desired:

   ```
   DoCmd.RunSQL sSQL
   ```

Comment: Unfortunatelly none of these solutions worked. All 3 throw the same error 3075. In this case it seems like it is not a function related problem.

Answer (score 2):

First, Access might think that the subquery may return more than one record, thus `Top 1` should be used.

Next, it makes no sense to order the records to be inserted, as records per definition carries no order unless you specify this in the target table or the query where that table is used as source.

Also, even if you insisted to sort the insert, Access can't do this, as it doesn't know the output for `AM`.

Thus, this will run:

```vb
sSQL = "SELECT tApplicant.applicationID, tApplicant.name, tApplicant.ID, tPreferences.fld3, " & _
       "NZ((SELECT Top 1 1 FROM tInfo WHERE tInfo.applicationID = tApplicant.applicationID), 0) AS AM " _
       "INTO " & sTable & " FROM tPreferences INNER JOIN tApplicant " & _
       "ON tPreferences.IDapplic = tApplicant.applicationID " & _
       "WHERE tPreferences.IDposit = " & rsRos!ID & ";"
CurrentDB.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
```

That said, Erik's suggestion to replace `Nz` with `Exists` is preferable as this will result in "clean SQL" which always will run faster:

```vb
sSQL = "SELECT tApplicant.applicationID, tApplicant.name, tApplicant.ID, tPreferences.fld3, " & _
       "EXISTS (SELECT Top 1 1 FROM tInfo WHERE tInfo.applicationID = tApplicant.applicationID) AS AM " _
       "INTO " & sTable & " FROM tPreferences INNER JOIN tApplicant " & _
       "ON tPreferences.IDapplic = tApplicant.applicationID " & _
       "WHERE tPreferences.IDposit = " & rsRos!ID & ";"
CurrentDB.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
```

Neither will this be sortable on `AM`. Also, it will in Access SQL return `-1` and `0` for `AM`. To obtain `1`, apply `ABS`:

```vb
sSQL = "SELECT tApplicant.applicationID, tApplicant.name, tApplicant.ID, tPreferences.fld3, " & _
       "ABS(EXISTS (SELECT Top 1 1 FROM tInfo WHERE tInfo.applicationID = tApplicant.applicationID)) AS AM " _
       "INTO " & sTable & " FROM tPreferences INNER JOIN tApplicant " & _
       "ON tPreferences.IDapplic = tApplicant.applicationID " & _
       "WHERE tPreferences.IDposit = " & rsRos!ID & ";"
CurrentDB.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
```

Comment: For the `Exists` variant, you can remove the `Top 1` since, if it returns more than a single record, it exists.

Comment: I understand that in general it makes no sense to order the records to be inserted in a table. It's just that in this case I need this to make for me like ~100 tables with ready results at once. Refering to the error now, as far as I understand the problem is the subquery in ORDER BY clause.